# Get the parent values in the arraylist from a list of decimal numbers

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have an arraylist with these values (the values can change):

```
1  
1.1
1.2
1.3
2  
2.1
2.2
2.3
3  
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
3.6
3.7
3.8
3.9
3.10
4  
4.1
4.1.1
4.1.1.1
4.1.1.2
4.1.2
4.1.2.1
4.1.2.2
4.2
4.2.1
4.2.2
4.3
5  
5.1
```

I need to identifiy the fathers value in an arraylist, for this case, the arraylist has this fathers values:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 4.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2, 5
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30zWw.png)

for example, in this picture the "fathers values" (1, 1.3) can't be selected, because it has child options.

I have an spinner in an android app, and I want to do something like that, the idea is in the spinner only parent values are hidden or cannot be selected. I don't have idea how can I do with this exercise.

Any idea? Please

Comment: What does "fathers value" mean?

Comment: Hi @khelwood look at this picture:
https://etutorials.org/shared/images/tutorials/tutorial_72/18fig16.gif
I mean "father value" as the number at the top of a list where the "child values" have the same number as the parent before the first period. In the case of the image, the parent values are 1 and 2, 3 does not count as a parent because it does not have "child values" that is, it does not have 3.1, 3.2, ... 3.N. In the case of the number 2.1 has "child values" like 2.1.1, 2.1.2, ... 2.1.N, the 2.1 number become as "father value".

Comment: You should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
List<String> list = List.of(
    "1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.3",
    "2", "2.1", "2.2", "2.3",
    "3", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.4", "3.5", "3.6", "3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10",
    "4", "4.1", "4.1.1", "4.1.1.1", "4.1.1.2", "4.1.2", "4.1.2.1", "4.1.2.2", "4.2", "4.2.1", "4.2.2", "4.3",
    "5", "5.1");
Set<String> fathers = list.stream()
    .map(e -> e.replaceAll("\\.\\d+$", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
System.out.println(fathers);
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4.1, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2, 5]
```